# Why isn't my "click" event listener working for my delete button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i'm am trying to make a my button with the class of delete( it is being created via like 34 on my javascript.) So I set up an onclick the same way I did for my submit button but nothing happens when It is clicked. It has a simple console log to test if it is working. What is wrong with my code?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#movie-search-submit').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var search_term = encodeURIComponent($('#movie-title-search').val()); //gets value from element
        var select_media = encodeURIComponent($('#media-select').val());
        console.log(search_term);
        console.log(select_media);
        var url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?country=US&term=' + search_term + '&media=' + select_media;


        var log_response = function(response) {
            $.each(response.results, function(key, item) {

                if (item.longDescription !== undefined) {
                    populate_listings(key, item);
                }

            });
        }


        $('.delete').on('click', function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             console.log("test");
         });


        var populate_listings = function(key, item) {
            var result_row = '<div id="result-' + key + '" class="row"></div>';
            $('#page-container').append(result_row);
            var title = '<div class="api-result col-md-2 title"><h2>' + item.trackName + '</h2></div>'
            var year = '<div class ="api-result col-md-4 year"><h4>' + item.releaseDate + '</h4></div>'
            var description = '<div class ="api-result col-md-4 description"><p>' + item.longDescription + '</p></div>'
            var delete_button =  '<div class="btn btn-lg btn-primary col-md-2 delete">Delete</div>';
            $('#result-' + key).append(title);
            $('#result-' + key).append(year);
            $('#result-' + key).append(description);
            $('#result-' + key).append(delete_button);

        }

        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: url,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: log_response,
        });
    });   
});
```

Comment: Add your delete onclick statement outside your submit onclick statement. Because currently in your implementation, delete onclick will be registered only if you click the submit button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.delete` button is not available when you are attaching the event to it. So delegate the event

```
$('body').on('click','.delete', function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             console.log("test");
         });
```